# After fixing "Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8" Android studio emulator still doesn't work

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, android-emulator

I got an error

> "Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using
> Java 1.8"

I change it in IDE settings and JAVA_HOME environment variable. Errors in the terminal and build disappeared but emulator still doesn't work.

My versions
[image: My versions]

Error in the emulator

[image: Error in the emulator]

The root cause of the problem

[image: The root cause of the problem]

*If anyone can, please help*

Comment: Click the **Gradle Settings** link that should appear in your **Build** panel on build failure, and then then set a matching JDK for gradle.

Comment: You can video solution here https://youtu.be/9mmY8rLvoRU

Answer (score 1):

The reason was obvious. I changed emulator, I don't understand why, but my ex emulator stopped working. I reinstall it many times (Nexus 5x), and changed api but it did not helped. Accidentally I installed Nexus 5 and all started work corectly.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem in react native `"react-native": "0.68.1"` in mac-m1 
 & Java version is 1.8, instead of upgrading to java-11 
i resolved error by running a diagnostic check using `npx @react-native-community/cli doctor` 
[What is purpose of latest doctor command in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58948466/what-is-purpose-of-latest-doctor-command-in-react-native)

Answer (score 0):

Change your Gradle settings to this :
[image: Not the Embedded JDK]

And keep the Gradle in App directory in v1.8 :
[image: App Gradle - Compile Option]

Comment: Still the same. My settings were like above(

Comment: Try to update the Android Emulator from the SDK Manager -> SDK Tools ->Android Emulator if the issue remains uninstall it than install it again

Answer (score 0):

Regards this type of issue we can create a demo to check the configuration.

For an instance, I created a demo with `Empty Activity` and using `Kotlin`.

The configuration looks like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.teststackoverflow"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

// Please check this
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

// Please check this
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}
```

And we also need to check the configuration on the menu of `Project Structure`   I always used the `Embedded JDK` which is in location of `Android Sutido`
Of course， you can specify other `JDK` you want to use.

Comment: Still the same. My settings were like above(

Comment: I double-checked your second screen (Error in the emulator), you mean that you can't launch the emulator, right?  I don't think your application can cause the problem (doesn't work).

Comment: Yes. So the error not in the application. Thank you. I will then look for problems in the emulator